# Please set root ViewContainerRef using setRootViewContainerRef in spec file jasmine after using ng6-toastr in project

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Please set root ViewContainerRef using setRootViewContainerRef error is coming on running test cases using ng test command.This issue is coming after using ng6-toastr in project.

below is piece of TestBed code :

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [FormsModule, TableModule, DialogModule, HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{
            path: 'Orders',
            component: PlanOrderComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'plan-order-history',
            component: PlanOrderHistoryComponent
        }
    ])],
    declarations: [HeaderComponent, SubheaderComponent, PlanOrderComponent, FilterPlanOrderPipe,
        PlanOrderHistoryComponent
    ],
    providers: [PlanOrderService,
        ConfirmationService, ToastsManager, ToastOptions, ViewContainerRef,
        DataServiceService, ClientService, AppService
    ]
}).compileComponents();

toastsManager = TestBed.get(ToastsManager);
viewContainerRef = TestBed.get(ViewContainerRef);
planOrderService = TestBed.get(PlanOrderService);
dataService = TestBed.get(DataServiceService);
dataService.CHAT_URL = 'ws://localhost:6320/';
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PlanOrderComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;

// toastsManager.setRootViewContainerRef(viewContainerRef);

originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 100000;
}));

it('Fetch plan orders from db : Success case', async(() => {
component.bannerLabel = 'Planning Orders';
const clientSer = TestBed.get(ClientService);

const mockPlanOrder: PlanOrderModel[] = [];

spyOn(planOrderService, 'getAllPlanOrders').and.returnValue(Observable.of < PlanOrderModel[] > (mockPlanOrder));
spyOn(clientSer, 'planOrders').and.returnValue(Observable.of < PlanOrderModel[] > (mockPlanOrder));

component.ngAfterViewInit();

fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(component.planOrders.length > 0).toBeTruthy();
});
}));
```

I have tried setting setRootViewContainerRef but after that it is giving 'No component factory found for ToastContain enter code here. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?' error

Comment: You're supposed to mock your dependencies. But if you don't, follow the error and add your component to the `entryComponents` array of your testbed.

Comment: I tried adding ToastContainer in entry component of test bed but it is throwing 'Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'entryComponents' does not exist in type 'TestModuleMetadata'.'

Comment: Because you have to override the testbed with `Testbed.configureTestingModule(...).overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, { set: { entryComponents: [ToastContainer] } })`. The syntax is horrific, that's why you're supposed to mock it.

Comment: I think i my work has been moved little ahead after adding it to entry components, but again got stuck with 'Component ToastContainer is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.' issue

Comment: Then please provide a [mcve] of your issue.